# Why are setlist settings for enumitem not honored?

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

In a test file the item numbers are indented more than the default and item text appears in the same column on wrapping lines as on the first line when I include the command

```
\setlist[enumerate,1] {labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=3\parindent}
```

In a larger file with the same setlist, the item number is not indented and the second line of the item text is not aligned with the text of the first line. Without the setlist the wrapped lines in an item are properly aligned with the first line but the label is not indented enough. The problem seems to be interference between \abstract and \setlist.

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1] {labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=3\parindent}

\begin{enumerate}
\item ordinal used as the limit of a sequence of consecutive ordinals,
e.g., $x_\alpha, \alpha \preceq Alpha$
\item ordinal used as the order type of a sequence of consecutive ordinals,
e.g., $x_\alpha, \alpha \prec Alpha$
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example, as small as possible, that shows the problem. And it should compile.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want? Incidentally, there's no `\Alpha` in the math alphabet since it's the same as an `A`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlist[enumerate,1] {wide=\parindent, leftmargin=3\parindent, itemindent=0pt, labelsep=*}

\begin{document}

In a larger file, the item number is not indented and the second line of the item text is not aligned with the text of the first line.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item ordinal used as the limit of a sequence of consecutive ordinals,
        e.g., $x_\alpha, α\preceq A$ blah blah blah.
  \item ordinal used as the order type of a sequence of consecutive ordinals,
        e.g., $x_\alpha, α ≺ A$ blah blah blah.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The large file includes a definition for \Alpha:

Comment: @shmuel: Which large file?

Comment: Please don't post code we can't compile. Anyway, is the layout what you wanted?

Comment: I tried the setlist from Bernard and and it shifted the item text left, truncating it and overlaying the item number. In answer to @Christian Hupfer, the where setlist failed included a definition of \Alpha; I edited the question to remove the dependency.

Comment: @shmuel: Did you try compiling just my code?

Comment: @Bernard, I replace my setlist with yours and ran it through pdflatex; the results were as I described.

Comment: @shmuel: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example? There must be something in the rest of your code which interferes with  my code.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, with a viable workaound. After some experimenting, I narrowed to problem down to the interaction between \abstract and \parindent. A \setlist using \parindent works if it precedes the \abstract, and a \setlist using explicit lengths instead of n\parlist works properly even after \abstract. The following code shows the error and the workaround.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\setlist[enumerate,1] {wide=\parindent, leftmargin=3\parindent, itemindent=0pt, labelsep=*}
Test with setlist before abstract

\begin{enumerate}
  \item ordinal used as the limit of a sequence of consecutive ordiinals,
        e.g., $x_\alpha, \alpha \preceq A$ blah blah blah.
  \item ordinal used as the order type of a sequence of consecutive ordinals,
        e.g., $x_\alpha, \alpha \prec A$ blah blah blah.
\end{enumerate}
\abstract{Test abstract interaction with setlist}
\section{Test abstract interaction with setlist}
\setlist[enumerate,1] { leftmargin=3\parindent, itemindent=0pt, labelindent=!, labelsep=*}

In a file with abstract, the item number is not indented and the second
line of the item text is not aligned with the text of the first line.
Test with setlist after abstract

Dummy paragraph, to show pararagraph indent.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item ordinal used as the limit of a sequence of consecutive ordiinals,
        e.g., $x_\alpha, \alpha \preceq A$ blah blah blah.
  \item ordinal used as the order type of a sequence of consecutive ordiinals,
        e.g., $x_\alpha, \alpha \prec A$ blah blah blah.
\end{enumerate}

Test without reference to parindent

\setlist[enumerate,1] { leftmargin=5em,        itemindent=0pt, labelindent=3em , labelsep=*}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item ordinal used as the limit of a sequence of consecutive ordiinals,
        e.g., $x_\alpha, \alpha \preceq A$ blah blah blah.
  \item ordinal used as the order type of a sequence of consecutive ordiinals,
        e.g., $x_\alpha, \alpha \prec A$ blah blah blah.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bernard, if I add an \abstract to your example then I get the same failure.

Comment: @Bernard, I've revised my answer to show an example of correct processing before the \abstract, incorrect output after the \abstract and a viable work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that \abstract{foo} was equivalent to

```
\begin{abstract}
foo
\end{foo}
```

Apparently not. If I change the document to use a begin/end pair instead of \abstract, then enumitem works as expected.

Comment: Your example code in the original post does not show this at all. You mildly mention this as part of the discussion, but it's not clear at all that you used `\abstract{foo}`.